# Battle academy type anime from the '90s/'00s where two girls fight in orbit

Tags: story-identification, anime

I am looking for an anime that spanned at least one 26 episode series and OVAs.

The main characters were all part of some academy/military that was protecting the city from monsters who would show up and attack. Pretty sure it was all girls; may be mistaken there. The main character was the usual daft-but-lovable redhead and the other main character was a stoic/cold dark-haired girl who often wore green.

The unique bit I recall is that the dark-haired character was actually a princess, lost long ago, and her lineage allowed her to control a super weapon; she is duped into using this and fights the main character in orbit above the planet, before eventually falling to her apparent, death.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like it might be [Mai-Otome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My-Otome), which ran for 26 episodes (plus some bonus material) and an OVA in 2005-2006. The setting (school for all-female magical warriors), protagonist (plucky redheaded main character type), and deuteragonist (serious dark-haired girl in green) all line up. Plot synopses are scant, but the details about the deuteragonist having a secret heritage and superweapon relevant to the finale appears to line up as well.

Synopsis on Wikipedia:

> My-Otome's story takes place in the distant future on the planet Earl, colonized by immigrants from Earth centuries ago. "Old technology" has survived in the form of nanomachines that allow female virgins to take the role of Meister Otomes - bodyguards, attendants and warriors that serve the royalty of various kingdoms.
>
> Arika Yumemiya has come to Windbloom Kingdom in search of her mother, whom Arika knows was an Otome. On her arrival she meets the top Coral Otome student, Nina Wáng, and Windbloom's heir to the throne, Mashiro Blan de Windbloom. The series follows Arika's progress as a student at Garderobe Academy and the machinations of those desiring the destructive power of the old technology for themselves.

From the episode summaries:

> Nagi discovers that the true heir to the throne might be Nina... Nina is forced to operate the Harmonium, a weapon capable of destroying entire cities... Arika comes into conflict with Nina in a final battle, having unlocked the true power of the Blue Sky Sapphire. Arika tells Nina that it is not too late to make up for her mistakes, and manages to defeat her even as the Harmonium takes possession of her

Comment: This is it! Thank you, legend.